# How to get JPEG file orientation using libjpeg

Tags: c++, ios, jpeg, libjpeg

I need to know what orientation has the JPEG file which i read.

```
jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);

jpeg_stdio_src(&cinfo, file);
jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
```

What shall i do after reading the header? Help please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The orientation is stored in the EXIF section.

I see two options here:

- Use `libexif`'s jpegtools, see for example:
  https://github.com/kif/imagizer/blob/master/libexiftran/jpegtools.c (look for the `get_orientation()` function)
- or use something like the `get_orientation()` function used in `http://src.gnu-darwin.org/ports/x11-toolkits/gtk20/work/gtk+-2.12.3/gdk-pixbuf/io-jpeg.c` to retrieve the orientation from the `j_decompress_ptr` directly. (this is probably the quickest-to-implement solution)

Comment: What shall i include to my xcode project to second method work?

Comment: You probably have to copy the `get_orientation()` function from this file and resolve any dependencies that are missing. Note that I rather encourage using a well-encapsulated library approach as in *(1)*.

Comment: I am asking because there are really a lot of dependencies and i see that it will take a lot of time. But ok, thank you really for helping where to find the solution